# New PC with new and old drives

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

so I ordered parts for a new PC that should arrive soon and here's the situation :
I want to transfer two drives with data on them from a non-working pc running windows 7 to a new computer that will have an SSD as it's main/booting drive and the two old drives at data drives.

Would installing windows 8 at the operation system for that new PC damage the datas on the old drives comming from a PC that ran windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would installing windows 8 as the operation system for that new PC
>   damage the datas on the old drives comming from a PC that ran windows
>   7?

No, as long as you don't format or re- partition them, why would installing Windows have any effect on these drives? The answer is it would not.

If you are even a little bit concerned, don't connect the drives until after you have installed Windows and have it booting properly.

Comment: Thank you! I just wasen't sure since it's the first time I'm doing something like this.

Comment: Your welcome, please be sure to mark my answer as accepted if it answers your question.